# Annotating/applying labels to classes in Eclipse package explorer

Tags: eclipse, package-explorer

Personally, I am a very visual-oriented sort of person.  A long list of classes, especially with similar names, in one package in Eclipse can be a pain to stare at.  Is there an Eclipse plugin or a way to annotate classes in the Package Explorer with colors?

I am aware of and currently use Eclipse working sets, but I would like to furtherly color-label the classes themselves in the package explorer list.

Seems like a pretty far-fetched request, but is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is an plugin call `Resource Decorator` Check this [blog](http://codeandme.blogspot.in/p/blog-page_7.html) for more details.

Check the motivation section:

> While working with mylyn and working sets helps to organize the workspace, I was always missing some visual distinction between different project types. Like having different colors for plug-ins and features or highlight important files.

You can use regular expression to decorate a set similar resources.